# SQL function to transform number with a certain pattern

Tags: sql

I need for a SQL query to transform an int with a value between 1 to 300000 to a number which has this pattern : always 8 number.

For example:
1 becomes 00000001,
123 becomes 00000123,
123456 becomes 00123456.

I have no idea how to do that... How can I do it?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you areusing.

Answer (score 2):

In Standard SQL, you can use this trick:

```
select substring(cast( (num + 100000000) as varchar(255)) from 2)
```

Few databases actually support this syntax.  Any given database can do what you want, but the method depends on the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

**For MS SQL Server**

You could use `FORMAT` function, like this:

```
SELECT FORMAT(123,'00000000')
```

[https://database.guide/how-to-format-numbers-in-sql-server/#:~:text=Starting%20from%20SQL%20Server%202012,the%20output%20should%20be%20formatted](https://database.guide/how-to-format-numbers-in-sql-server/#:%7E:text=Starting%20from%20SQL%20Server%202012,the%20output%20should%20be%20formatted).

Read at the link **Leading Zeroes**

**For MySql/Oracle**

You could use LPAD, like this:

```
SELECT LPAD('123',8,'0')
```

https://database.guide/how-to-add-leading-zeros-to-a-number-in-mysql/